# An std::move function of C++ standard 11 implementation in C

Tags: c++, c, c++11, std

We are all aware of the powerful functionality of the std::move function that is implemented in the C++ standard 11, where it moves the elements in a specific range into a new range.

I would like to know if I can develop such a functionality in  pure C code. My code is written in C and I want to have something similar to the std::move function of C++, where I can move the range of integer elements into a new range without using a temporary buffer.

Comment: `std::move` doesn't move anything it's just a type cast.

Comment: A cast to a type that, AFAIK, has no counterpart in C. Without r-value references it will be hard to mimic move semantics.

Comment: "move" is the same as "copy" for integers, so just copy them

Comment: I think you misunderstand what "move semantics" are in C++11.  It has nothing to do with ranges; moving a range is just moving one element, repeated. It sounds like you are describing `memmove`, which is an unrelated idea. That really means "memcpy but allow for overlapping range" and of course, C already has it.

Comment: @101010 It seems that OP is describing another [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your text:

> ... moves the elements in a specific range into a new range.

and:

> ... where I can move a range of integer elements into a new range without using a temporary buffer.

I think the thing you're after is `memmove`. It's like `memcpy` but handles overlapping regions without issue.

For example, the following code moves (copies, really) elements from the range 3 through 6 (zero-based) to the range 2 through 5:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int xyzzy[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    memmove (&(xyzzy[2]), &(xyzzy[3]), sizeof(*xyzzy) * 4);
    printf ("{ %d", xyzzy[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(xyzzy) / sizeof(*xyzzy); i++)
        printf (", %d", xyzzy[i]);
    printf (" }\n");

    return 0;
}
```

which basically does:

```
 {0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}
        | | | |
       / / / /
      | | | |
      V V V V
 {0 1 3 4 5 6 6 7 8 9}
```

Comment: @skypjack, based on the text, I believe my interpretation is correct, to wit: `move a range of integer elements into a new range`.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look to a possible implementation of `std::move`:

```
template <typename T>
typename remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& arg) {
  return static_cast<typename remove_reference<T>::type&&>(arg);
}
```

You'll see that `std::move` all it does is to `static_cast` its input argument to a rvalue reference. Thus, there's no "move" from `std::move`.

Now, the move mechanism in C++11 and beyond is based on rvalue references. C doesn't have even simple references. Consequently, it's nearly impossible to implement such a mechanism in C, since the basic facilities are absent.

In C you'll have to stick to moving around data via pointers.